# How can I replace and return the replaced text in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am shifting an image tag from one place to another. It currently takes 2 regular expressions, one to find the image tag and one to replace it. Can this be done with one regular expression?

```
<?php
// Always shorttag
$thumbnail_match_result = preg_match('{<\s*img.*?/>}',  $thumbnail, $matches);
$thumbnail_tag = array_shift($matches);
$thumbnail_caption = preg_replace('{<\s*img.*?/>}',"", $thumbnail);
?>

<h4><?php print $title ?></h4>
<a title="<?php print $title ?>" href="<?php print $original_image ?>" data-gallery=""> 
  <?php print $thumbnail_tag ?>
</a>
<?php print $thumbnail_caption; ?>
```

Thumbnail looks like:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="/files/styles/photocomp_large/public/lovejoymask400mm_0.jpg?itok=pqICHn8s" width="960" height="656" alt="aly" title="title" />    <blockquote class="image-field-caption">test</blockquote>
```

Comment: What is an example of `$thumbnail`?

Comment: I added $thumbnail to the question.

Comment: It would be more reliable if you used a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$thumbnail_tag='';
$thumbnail_caption = preg_replace_callback('{<\s*img.*?/>}', function($m) 
        use(&$thumbnail_tag) { $thumbnail_tag=$m[0]; return '';}, $thumbnail);
```

Check values:

```
echo $thumbnail_tag . "\n";
//=> <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="/files/styles/photocomp_large/public/lovejoymask400mm_0.jpg?itok=pqICHn8s" width="960" height="656" alt="aly" title="title" />

echo $thumbnail_caption . "\n";
//=>    <blockquote class="image-field-caption">test</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two capture groups, one for each part (image tag, text), like this:

```
preg_match('{(<\s*img.*?/>)(.*)}',  $thumbnail, $matches);
```

Then `$matches` will contain the complete matched string in index 0, which you don't need, but in index 1 and 2 you will find the captured groups:

```
 print $matches[1]; // <img ... />
 print $matches[2]; // <blocknote>text...
```